# the public type must be defined in its own file

Tags: java

So i am watching tutorials this is the code

```
abstract class AnonymousInner {
   public abstract void mymethod();
}

public class OuterClass {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      AnonymousInner inner = new AnonymousInner() {
         public void mymethod( ) {
            System.out.println("this is an example of anonymous inner class");
         }
      };
      inner.mymethod();
   }
}
```

but after i type in this is not working cause the OuterClass "the public type must be defined in its own file"

Don't know why and asking for help.

Comment: File name must be OuterClass.java

Comment: Not 100% sure but you may need to put the AnonymousInner INSIDE the OuterClass's parenthesis "{}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the name of the file? It should be OuterClass.java.